# jquery only hover outside child element

Tags: jquery, hover

HI,

I am trying to hide a child div when you hover on the parent div outside the child, any ideas how I can do this using jquery?

At the moment using the hover function, it hides the child div when I hover anywhere over the parent, including when over the child.

[alt text http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/1794/82560121.gif](http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/1794/82560121.gif)

Answer (score 1):

You can go about something like this:

```
$('div').hover(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('id') === 'parentdiv') {
    $('div#childdiv').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey sAc, thanks for the quick answer, but it doesn't seme to work for me... i've commented my code above...

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div#parentdiv").hover(function () {
  $("div:child").hide("slow", function () {
    // use callee so don't have to name the function
    $(this).prev().hide("slow", arguments.callee); 
  });
});
```